# Why are IHttpHandler Request.Params correct on first call, but NULL on second call?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, httphandler

I have an HTML/Javascript page that is making a jQuery ajax call to a .NET ajax handler (.ASHX).  On the first call, the parameters I am passing in the data object are present and correct.  But in subsequent calls, they are NULL.

JavaScript setup:

```
var data = {

    requestType: "RecentMXMeetings",
    meetingType: "Maintenance",
    baseDate: "6/15/2016",
    daysPast: 90, 
    daysFuture: 30
}

$.ajax({

    type: "GET", 
    url: "ajaxHandler.ashx",
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    data: data,

    success: function (result) {
        alert("Success: " + result.responseText);
    },

    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error: " + result.responseText);
    },

    fail: function (result) {
        alert("Error - Fail: " + result.responseText);
    },

    always: function (result) {
        alert("Always: " + result.responseText);
    }

});
```

Handler code (.ashx):

```
public class ajaxHandler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {

        string retJSON = "NODATA";

        var x = context.Request.Params["requestType"];


        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)) {

            switch (x) {

                case "RecentMXMeetings":
                    retJSON = SerialiseRecentMeetings(context);
                    break;

                    // other cases...

            }
        }

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(retJSON);
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //
    // SerialiseRecentMeetings() and other methods...
    //

}
```

I add a breakpoint on "`var x = context....`".  On the first run, x == "RecentMXMeetings".  On the second and subsequence runs, x == null.

Here's what I've been able to determine in debugging it:

If I change the ajax type from "GET" to "POST" and run it, then change it back to "GET" and run it again, the data object parameters are returned correctly for one time, and then subsequent calls are NULL again.  Switching back and forth between "GET" and "POST" fixes the problem for one call.

The problem is intermittent.  Sometimes after four or five runs, x will come back "RecentMXMeetings", and then go back to null again.

Waiting for a while in between runs will sometimes "reset" it and it will be good for that run.  Then go back to being null again.

This is my first foray into ajax handlers in C#, so I am quite the novice at this.

Is this a caching problem?  Is there an async issue here?  Am I perhaps not using or disposing of the HttpHandler properly?

Comment: Can you use `POST` instead of `GET`?

Comment: try using fiddler to view your network traffic and see if the HttpHandler is actually getting the query string every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my problem was not related to the code itself, per se, but how I was running the project.

Visual Studio, when you click on the "Start Debug" button will start the solution at it's root document (ie, index.html).  That is UNLESS the current open document is of a runnable type, such as .html.  If your current open window is one of your class files (ie, .cs), it will not attempt to run the class file, but will start the debug session at your root document.

However, it WILL attempt to run a Generic Handler (.ashx) all by itself if that is the document you currently have open.  And, by doing so, it was not starting at the index.html page which issues my ajax calls and sends parameters to the Handler.  So, my Params collection was null because it was literally null.  Running the .ashx by itself supplies no parameters.

So, the reason it worked after changing my call type from GET to POST and Back to GET again is because in doing so, I opened the index.html file to make that change, and when I started my debug session again, my current document was the index.html file, not the Generic Handler .ashx file.

I should probably lose a hundred reputations points just for making this dumb of a mistake.  But in case it helps others, there it is.